# Ждать выполнения фоновых процессов в Python/multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
        chunk_size = count_lines() // 4
        for n in range(4):
            name = 'prcss'+str(n)
            st_chunk = n * (chunk_size+1)
            fn_chunk = st_chunk + chunk_size
            multiprocessing.Process(target=func,
                                    name=name,
                                    args=(hpass, st_chunk, fn_chunk),
                                    daemon=True).start()
```

Цикл запускает несколько фоновых процессов, без создания объектов этих самых процессов, поэтому куда прилепить метод .join не пойму. Как иначе заставить ждать основной процесс?

Comment: "без создания объектов этих самых процессов" - у вас в коде буквально идет создание объектов процессов (Process), просто вы их никуда не сохраняете. В целом, для задач с распределением данных обработки на нескольких процессах удобно использовать multiprocessing.Pool (первый же пример в документации по multiprocessing: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#introduction).

Comment: Неправльно выразился, я имел ввиду, что без привязки имени к объекту, .join не вызвать. За подсказку про Pool - спасибо, попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем не стал ломать голову и сделал с именами, как положено:

```
chunk_size = count_lines() // 4
prcss_lst = []
for n in range(4):
    name = 'prcss'+str(n)
    st_chunk = n * (chunk_size+1)
    fn_chunk = st_chunk + chunk_size
    print(name, st_chunk, fn_chunk)
    prc = multiprocessing.Process(target=func,
                            name=name,
                            args=(hpass, st_chunk, fn_chunk),
                            daemon=True)
    prc.start()
    prcss_lst.append(prc)
    
for p in prcss_lst:
    p.join()
```

Процессы отрабатывают, скрипт продолжается.